# urxvt not working and xterm works for same command

Tags: shell, xterm, rxvt

`xterm -e 'sudo iotop -aP'` working
`urxvt -e 'sudo iotop -aP'` not working

`top` command is working for both

any idea what's happening?
how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in xterm, because xterm tries more than once, executing the command as given or via an [execvp-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541910/how-to-use-execvp).  In the first case, that treats all of the tokens after `-e` as a single string, in the latter the tokens have to be **separated** (for the execvp-call).  That's a side-effect of its interface with [`luit`](https://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html), which may not be obvious from the [manual page mention](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:localeFilter):

> When using a locale-filter, e.g., with the **`-e`** option, or the
> shell, ***xterm*** first tries passing control via that filter.  If
> it fails, ***xterm*** will retry without the locale-filter.  ***Xterm***
> warns about the failure before retrying.

But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/main.c#L5010) would make it clearer (**`command_to_exec`** is the array of strings used for the [`-e` option](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/main.c#L2277), while **`command_to_exec_with_luit`** is the combined command-string first-tried by ***xterm***).

Most terminal emulators don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

removing quotes worked

```
urxvt -e sudo iotop -aP
```